# When I want to upgrade laravel 9 to 10 I get dependancy errors. How can I solved that?

Tags: php, laravel, dependencies, composer-php, upgrade

In my composer.json file

previously the dependency are:

```
"require": {
        "php": "^8.0.2",
        "darkaonline/l5-swagger": "^8.4",
        "ejarnutowski/laravel-api-key": "^1.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^9.19",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^3.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.7",
        "spatie/laravel-activitylog": "^4.7",
        "spatie/laravel-permission": "^5.8",
        "tomfordrumm/jwt-auth": "dev-develop"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.7",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/pint": "^1.0",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^6.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^1.0"
    },`
```

Now i have upgrade the dependency to this:

```
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.1",
        "darkaonline/l5-swagger": "^8.4",
        "ejarnutowski/laravel-api-key": "^1.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^10.0",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^3.2",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.8",
        "spatie/laravel-activitylog": "^4.7",
        "spatie/laravel-permission": "^5.8",
        "tomfordrumm/jwt-auth": "dev-develop"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.7",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/pint": "^1.0",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.18",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^7.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^10.0",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^2.0.0"
    },
```

But I have this errors:

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

```
  Problem 1
- illuminate/support[v5.6.0, ..., v5.8.36] require php ^7.1.3 -> your php version (8.2.2) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/support[v6.0.0, ..., v6.19.1] require php ^7.2 -> your php version (8.2.2) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/support[v7.0.0, ..., v7.28.4] require php ^7.2.5 -> your php version (8.2.2) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/support[v8.0.0, ..., v8.11.2] require php ^7.3 -> your php version (8.2.2) does not satisfy that requirement.
- Root composer.json requires tomfordrumm/jwt-auth dev-develop -> satisfiable by tomfordrumm/jwt-auth[dev-develop].
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v10.0.2 (conflict analysis result)
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v10.0.3 (conflict analysis result)
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v10.1.0 (conflict analysis result)
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v10.1.1 (conflict analysis result)
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v10.1.2 (conflict analysis result)
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v10.1.3 (conflict analysis result)
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v10.1.4 (conflict analysis result)
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v10.1.5 (conflict analysis result)
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v10.0.1 (conflict analysis result)
- tomfordrumm/jwt-auth dev-develop requires illuminate/support ^5.2|^6|^7|^8|^9 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.2.0, ..., v5.8.36, v6.0.0, ..., v6.20.44, v7.0.0, ..., v7.30.6, v8.0.0, ..., v8.83.27, v9.0.0, ..., v9.52.4].
- Only one of these can be installed: illuminate/support[v5.2.0, ..., v5.8.36, v6.0.0, ..., v6.20.44, v7.0.0, ..., v7.30.6, v8.0.0, ..., v8.83.27, v9.0.0, ..., v9.52.4, v10.0.0, ..., v10.1.5], laravel/framework[v10.0.0, ..., v10.1.5]. laravel/framework replaces illuminate/support and thus cannot coexist with it.
- Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^10.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v10.0.0, ..., v10.1.5].
```

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.

My php version is: PHP 8.2.2

**I have tried:**

> composer update --with-all-dependencies

And also changed the `tomfordrumm/jwt-auth` to `tymon/jwt-auth` but still having same error

**In documentation:**

PHP 8.1.0 Required
Laravel now requires PHP 8.1.0 or greater.

Composer 2.2.0 Required
Laravel now requires Composer 2.2.0 or greater.

Composer Dependencies
You should update the following dependencies in your application's composer.json file:

- laravel/framework to ^10.0
- laravel/sanctum to ^3.2
- doctrine/dbal to ^3.0
- spatie/laravel-ignition to ^2.0

If you are upgrading to Sanctum 3.x from the 2.x release series, please consult the Sanctum upgrade guide.

Furthermore, if you wish to use PHPUnit 10, you should delete the processUncoveredFiles attribute from the  section of your application's phpunit.xml configuration file. Then, update the following dependencies in your application's composer.json file:

- nunomaduro/collision to ^7.0
- hpunit/phpunit to ^10.0

Finally, examine any other third-party packages consumed by your application and verify you are using the proper version for Laravel 10 support.

Minimum Stability
You should update the minimum-stability setting in your application's composer.json file to stable:

"minimum-stability": "stable",

Application

Comment: Please share more details, like the full and exact error message. I would assume that not all the packages you use are compatible with Laravel 10 yet, like the mentioned `tomfordrumm/jwt-auth` which hasn't seen any updates since Jul 14 2022 - Laravel v10 was released in 2023

Comment: Yes.. I have edit the errors. You can see now

Comment: Also, please share your attempts to resolve the problem. Check whether changing from the forked `tomfordrumm/jwt-auth` to the original `tymon/jwt-auth` helps

Comment: I have tried with --with-all-dependencies but returning the same problem and also change `tomfordrumm/jwt-auth` to `tymon/jwt-auth` but still same error

Comment: Please add all calrification to your question by editing it

Comment: "but still having same error" - you changed the dependency from tomfordrumm/jwt-auth to tymon/jwt-auth, but `composer update`  still yields a problem with the first package?

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of tomfordrumm/jwt-auth does not support laravel v10. so remove tomfordrumm/jwt-auth from composer and add this package:

"tymon/jwt-auth": "^2.0"